# Displaying a PyQt Chart in a PyQt Window after a button click

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am using PyQT and QtDesigner to build a simple(!) GUI Application for a University project.

A MainWindow shows a few simple labels and text boxes (salary, pension contribution percentage, asks if user has a student loan).  Once click and a 'calculate' button is clicked, the idea is that a QtChart (simple pie chart for now), will display is some pre-defined space at the bottom of the form.  I have added a Widget to the bottom of the form, can perform all of the calculations correctly and plot the chart, but I do not know how to set the property of the Widget so that it displays the chart.

I've watched tons of tutorials and read lots of articles but can't seem to find examples that are doing this in the same way.  A less that ideal alternative would be to launch a new window which shows the chart, but really I would like to display in a pre-defined space in my gui so that I have full control over the UI experience.

I have added the relevant sections of code below, and would be eternally grateful if anyone could tell me where I am going wrong!  Many thanks.

```
# main.py

import sys
import gui

# app_choice = 'mail'
app_choice = 'salary'
# app_choice = 'todo_list'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = gui.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = gui.QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    if app_choice == 'mail':
        ui = gui.Ui_MainWindowMail()
    elif app_choice == 'salary':
        ui = gui.Ui_MainWindowTax()
    elif app_choice == 'todo_list':
        raise ValueError('This app is still being built!')
    else:
        raise ValueError('An incorrect app choice was made.')

    ui.setupUi(win)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


# gui.py

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import mail
import tax
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QPieSeries, QPieSlice
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Ui_MainWindowMail(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(362, 255)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_send = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_send.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 190, 81, 31))
        self.btn_send.setObjectName("btn_send")
        self.btn_send.clicked.connect(self.btn_send_click)  # Call the 'clicked' function when button is clicked
        self.lbl_to = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_to.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 51, 21))
        self.lbl_to.setObjectName("lbl_to")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 111, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.txt_to = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txt_to.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 211, 20))
        self.txt_to.setObjectName("txt_to")
        self.txt_msg = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txt_msg.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 211, 131))
        self.txt_msg.setDocumentTitle("")
        self.txt_msg.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 362, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Send Email Tool"))
        self.btn_send.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send Email"))
        self.lbl_to.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send to:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Email message:"))

    def btn_send_click(self):
        if self.txt_to.text() != "" and self.txt_msg.toPlainText() != "":
            mail.send_mail(self.txt_to.text(), self.txt_msg.toPlainText())
            self.txt_to.setText("")
            self.txt_msg.setText("")
            qm = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            qm.setWindowTitle("Send Email Tool")
            qm.setText("Email sent")
            qm.exec()
        else:
            qm = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
            qm.setWindowTitle("Send Email Tool - ERROR")
            qm.setText("Some information is missing.  Please check and try again.")
            qm.exec()


class Ui_MainWindowTax(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(465, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 371, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName("label_title")
        self.label_salary = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_salary.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 240, 21))
        self.label_salary.setObjectName("label_salary")
        self.txt_salary = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txt_salary.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 60, 161, 20))
        self.txt_salary.setObjectName("txt_salary")
        self.label_pension = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_pension.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 221, 16))
        self.label_pension.setObjectName("label_pension")
        self.spin_pension = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spin_pension.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 100, 51, 22))
        self.spin_pension.setObjectName("spin_pension")
        self.combo_student_loan = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.combo_student_loan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 140, 69, 22))
        self.combo_student_loan.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.combo_student_loan.setEditable(True)
        self.combo_student_loan.setObjectName("combo_student_loan")
        self.combo_student_loan.addItem("")
        self.combo_student_loan.addItem("")
        self.label_student_loan = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_student_loan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 211, 16))
        self.label_student_loan.setObjectName("label_student_loan")
        self.button_calculate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_calculate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 401, 41))
        self.button_calculate.setObjectName("button_calculate")
        self.button_calculate.clicked.connect(self.button_calculate_click)  # Call the 'clicked' function when button is clicked
        self.widget_chart = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_chart.setObjectName("widget_chart")
        self.widget_chart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 240, 381, 331))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 465, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Salary Calculator"))
        self.label_title.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Salary Calculator"))
        self.label_salary.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please enter you gross salary to the nearest £:"))
        self.label_pension.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please select your pension contribution (%):"))
        self.combo_student_loan.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "No"))
        self.combo_student_loan.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Yes"))
        self.combo_student_loan.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "No"))
        self.label_student_loan.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Do you have a student loan?"))
        self.button_calculate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculate!"))

    def button_calculate_click(self):

        # Get values entered into the form
        salary = self.txt_salary.text()
        salary = int(salary)
        student_loan_flag = self.combo_student_loan.currentText()
        pension_contribution = self.spin_pension.value()

        # Calculate income tax deductions
        income_tax = tax.calculate_income_tax(salary)
        ni = salary * 0.01

        # Calculate pension deduction
        pension = salary * (pension_contribution / 100)

        # Calculate student loan deduction
        student_loan_pay_threshold = 19895  # Plan 1 repayment threshold.  ToDo: Update to work for all loan plans
        if student_loan_flag == 'No' or salary < student_loan_pay_threshold:
            student_loan = 0
        else:
            student_loan = (salary - student_loan_pay_threshold) * 0.09

        # Calculate Net Pay
        net_pay = salary - income_tax - ni - pension - student_loan

        # Create PyQt chart
        series = QPieSeries()
        series.setHoleSize(0.1)
        series.append("Income Tax", income_tax)
        series.append("NI", ni)
        series.append("Pension", pension)
        series.append("Student Loan", student_loan)
        series.append("Net Pay", net_pay)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)
        chart.setTheme(QChart.ChartThemeLight)

        chartview = QChartView(chart)
        chartview.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        #self.widget_chart.setLayout(chartview)
```

Comment: You could try creating an intermediate layout containing the chart view and set that, not sure if it'd work

Answer (score 0):

Add the chart widget to your layout, then use its QWidget show() hide() slots as needed.